Streamlit: How to check clicked condition for CSS styled buttons?
This page of the Streamlit documentation shows how to style a button with CSS and I'm using that to generate a custom button as
enabled = True

st.markdown(f"""
        <style>
        .custom-button {{
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        }}
        .custom-button:hover {{
        opacity: 0.6;
        }}
        .disabled {{
        opacity: 0.6;
        cursor: not-allowed;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        }}
        </style>
        <button class="{"custom-button" if enabled else "disabled"}">
        Run!
        </button>
        """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

This indeed renders the button I want on the screen, but then how do I interact with it? (check whether it has been clicked and so on)

As it always happens, after a day and a half of struggling with this problem I decide to post the question, and half an hour after that I find an answer to it on this post.
The following code does exactly what I wanted: it gives a custom CSS format to a button (more details on the linked post)
import streamlit as st

st.markdown("""
<style>
.element-container:has(#run) + div button {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
}
.element-container:has(#run) + div button:hover {
        opacity: 0.6;
}
.element-container:has(#dis) + div button {
    opacity: 0.6;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)


st.markdown('<span id="run"></span>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
if st.button('Enabled button'):
    st.write("works!")

st.markdown('<span id="dis"></span>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
if st.button('Disabled button'):
    st.write("works!")

